# Can I optimize a 4K file so it will direct play on my 4K tv?

Tags: video, conversion, tv, codec, plex

I have a handful of 4K files I'd like to play locally over my network, (everything hardwired with cat6), to my 4K TV. Can Plex pre-transcode the files so I can view them stutter-free?

My server doesn't seem to handle 4K transcodes very smoothly so I'm interested in converting them to a format and container that my TV can Direct Play.

If Plex can't do it, what conversion applications do you guys use for jobs like this?

Comment: Handbrake is a great free program for converting video files. Allows a lot of customisation of the output file. You can also queue up multiple jobs with the same settings.